# Joomla add param to extension

Tags: joomla

I fix /administrator/components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml

with

```
<field name="turbobit" type="text"
label="Turbobit" description="Turbobit"
class="inputbox" size="60" />
```

and /administrator/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/edit.php

with

```
<li><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('turbobit'); ?>
<?php echo $this->form->getInput('turbobit'); ?></li>
```

but when I press save this field doesn't store in database

Where I must fix code more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in short, you need to add a column named "turbobit" in jos_content table in the database

take a look at my other answer: [Add new image field to Joomla 1.7 com_content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747365/add-new-image-filed-to-joomla-1-7-com-content/7797822#7797822) , which might be helpfull